# docker-compose volumes syntax for local driver to mount a file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am attempting to mount a file (nginx.conf) in the `volumes` section of my `docker-compose.yml`. I can mount a directory as a volume without issue, however, it is not clear to me what the syntax is for a file.

I have the following defined in my `volumes` section

```
volumes:
    roundcubeweb:
      driver: local
      driver_opts:
        type: none
        o: bind
        device: /mnt/docker/volumes/roundcube/html
    nginxconf:
      driver: local
      driver_opts:
        type: none    
        o: bind
        device: /mnt/docker/volumes/roundcube/nginx.conf
```

Later on, I have the following under my services section

```
nginx:
  image: nginx:latest
  deploy:
    replicas: 1
  restart: always
  depends_on: 
    - roundcube
  ports:
    - "8082:80"
  volumes:
    - roundcubeweb:/var/www/html
    - nginxconf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

When I attempt to start this up, I receive the following error:

> ERROR: for roundcube_nginx_1  Cannot create container for service
>   nginx: failed to mount local volume: mount /mnt/docker
>   /volumes/roundcube/nginx.conf:/var/lib/docker/volumes/roundcube_nginxconf/_data,
>   flags: 0x1000: not a directory
>
> ERROR: for nginx  Cannot create container for service nginx: failed to
>   mount local volume: mount /mnt/docker/volumes/rou
>   ndcube/nginx.conf:/var/lib/docker/volumes/roundcube_nginxconf/_data,
>   flags: 0x1000: not a directory ERROR: Encountered errors while
>   bringing up the project.

I've found that if I inline the file location in the nginx service section's volume declaration then it works just fine. For example:

```
   volumes:  
    - roundcubeweb:/var/www/html  
    - /mnt/docker/volumes/roundcube/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Can one not mount a file in the `volumes` section? Is there a reference for the local driver's parameters?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem on my Ubuntu machine (though I was mapping directories, not files).  I was trying to port my Docker-compose "environment" (i.e. cluster of containers) from a Windows machine to Ubuntu.  On Windows, I could only get the environment to work (with `docker-compose up`) if I used the top-level `volumes:` notation.  On Ubuntu, it would only work if I "inlined" the volumes container in the way you've explained in your question.  My point is that this doesn't seem to be a problem with files vs directories.

Comment: After a bit more investigation, I noticed that switching off WSL2 (on a Windows host) changes the behaviour of how volumes are bound. Switching off WSL2 in Windows makes the behaviour like Ubuntu -> it fails to mount the directory when using the `volumes:` format, but works if using the inline format.  (As an aside, WSL2 is _*extremely*_ slow in accessing the host file-system, and should be avoided at all cost!!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to have a standalone Docker volume point to a specific file rather than a directory. It may be related to a Docker design on how volumes are managed and mounted (tried to find a doc or related piece of code but could not find any)

`local` driver's parameter seems to take similar parameter as Linux [`mount`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) commands. It seems implied in [Docker volume doc](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#choose-the--v-or---mount-flag) though not very clearly:

> the local driver accepts mount options as a comma-separated list in the o parameter

---

> I've found that if I inline the file location in the nginx service section's volume declaration then it works just fine. For example:
>
> ```
> volumes:  
>  - roundcubeweb:/var/www/html  
>  - /mnt/docker/volumes/roundcube/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
> ```

In your example you are doing a [Bind Mound](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) rather than using [Volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/), which is handled differently by Docker and more suited for your use case of mounting a local *file* in the container. I think using Bind Mount is the appropriate solution in your case.